# SPD Rest service: Loop through multivalue Person/Group field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

**Question:**

1) How to set up a REST/HTTP call in SharePoint Designer so you can loop through Multi-Value Person field and do something for each reference found?

2)Is it possible to use said reference (f.e. store it an SPD variable) and use that variable when creating a new list entry?

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'd like to make a REST-call and get all Groups mentioned in a Person/Group multi-value field of a single List entry. 
The Persons/Groups will then asumeably be stored in a dictionary. Then for each Person/Group in the dictionary, I'd like to create a new entry in a seperate list, and assign it to said Person/Group (so no more multi-value field).

**What is/isnt working**

I can set up a REST call that queues for a set of items and do an action for each item, so the SPD code and loop seem to work.

But, the moment I create the REST call that requests the field values of the multi-value Person field, the set of results seems empty (in the picture below, int_RESToutputcount is 0). But if I look at the XML returned manually, the information is definitially there, so my best guess is that the feed returned is slightly different for some reason and thus I need to change my SPD 'code' respectively.

**Why I'm trying to do this:**

First off, unfortunately I'm bounded to using SPD, Infopath and the web UI. No server access, no custom code.

What I have:
- Custom list (Productieschema): Taskname, Start Date, Due Date

- Task list  (Task List): Lookup:list1(id), Person, Description, Completed

The idea is that 1 task has to be completed by multiple Groups (any of the participant can mark it complete). They have to be able to add commentary+an attachment. The groups shouldn't be able to see/edit each other's items (without going out of there way).

Each task would be assigned to 3-10 groups, meaning for each task, you'd have to enter 1 entry in list 1 and 3-10 entries in list 2. This means a lot of manual work as we have around 100 tasks. These tasks also come back roughly each year.

My solution would be to create a list 0. In this list we have all the fields of List 1 + a multi-value Person field. Then I'd like to create a workflow that
1) Creates an entry in list 1
2) Creates an entry for each Person/Group mentioned, and set its LookupId to the Id in list 1

**Other alternatives**

I have thought of using 'start a task process' and not bother with splitting up the tasks, but we want to have a 'monitor page' that allows us to see exactly which tasks are completed and which aren't. Also, each person has to be able to enter some reasoning, assign a status and add an attachment. Also, they should not see each others' tasks. AFAIK the 'start a task process' option doesn't allow for these requirements

**Attachments**

URL it works with (queues for all items, used to test my loop, it works but its useless of course)
`<site>/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'894750BE-5D64-46DD-AC70-7AACB7906F0D')/Items`

URL it doesn't work with and I don't understand why (queues for the 'assigned to' field of entry with )

```
<site>/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'894750BE-5D64-46DD-AC70-7AACB7906F0D')/Items(<id>)?$select=AssignedTo/Name,AssignedTo/ID&$expand=AssignedTo/Name,AssignedTo/ID
```

The XML I get with the last webcall

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><entry xml:base="https://sharepoint.utwente.nl/Team/FEZ/Planning_Control/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" m:etag="&quot;6&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'894750be-5d64-46dd-ac70-7aacb7906f0d')/Items(13)</id><category term="SP.Data.Task_x005f_OverviewListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'894750be-5d64-46dd-ac70-7aacb7906f0d')/Items(13)" /><link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/AssignedTo" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="AssignedTo" href="Web/Lists(guid'894750be-5d64-46dd-ac70-7aacb7906f0d')/Items(13)/AssignedTo"><m:inline><feed><id>96fc4741-c4e7-45ed-be11-e877a071451e</id><title /><updated>2017-02-24T15:57:02Z</updated><entry><id>efcec82b-c0a3-42dc-aff5-9e26ac6be8f6</id><category term="SP.Data.UserInfoItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><title /><updated>2017-02-24T15:57:02Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Name>FEZ Planning &amp; Control monitor (CES)</d:Name><d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">38</d:ID></m:properties></content></entry><entry><id>b2fa7303-3dbc-4d0a-8df2-fedd226a44a9</id><category term="SP.Data.UserInfoItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><title /><updated>2017-02-24T15:57:02Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Name>FEZ Planning &amp; Control monitor (FA)</d:Name><d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">41</d:ID></m:properties></content></entry></feed></m:inline></link><title /><updated>2017-02-24T15:57:02Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml" /></entry>
```

(This specific entry has 2 Groups assigned which I want to use, namely:)

`<d:Name>FEZ Planning &amp; Control monitor (CES)</d:Name><d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">38</d:ID>`

and

```
<d:Name>FEZ Planning &amp; Control monitor (FA)</d:Name><d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">41</d:ID>
```

My SPD workflow looks as follows:
(note: it should create 1 item in List Productieschema, and 1 item for each Person/Group resulted from the rest call)

[Click here for SPD screencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSKZg.jpg)